# Jacobian in SE(3)

Tags: lie-algebras, robotics

I have the following 3D composition of SE(3) elements:
$$
Z = (X \ T)^{-1} \ Y T = T^{-1} X^{-1} Y T
$$

Following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.01537.pdf) I have managed to compute the jacobians of $\log Z$ wrt $\log X$ and $\log Y$ (unless I have made a typo):
$$
\frac{\partial \log Z}{\partial \log X} = Adj(Y T)^{-1} * (-Adj(XT)) * Adj(T)^{-1}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial \log Z}{\partial \log Y} = I* Adj(T)^{-1}
$$

Now I would like to compute the jacobian of $\log Z$ wrt $\log T$, but I can't find the way of applying the chain rule correctly. Can anyone give me any hint?

Cheers!